# Blender gltf exporter model is dark

Tags: three.js, blender, aframe, gltf

I have a .OBJ model that I imported into Blender (2.79) and trying to export to .gtlf using the following exporter - https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter.

Here is the model - [Model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4ai3c0gus97v3o/Original%20Model.zip?dl=0)

Here are my export settings in Blender

[image]

The model looks bright and has texture when I view it in the texture mode in Blender but the exported gltf model looks really dark in a-frame.

Here is how it looks in blender
[image]

and this is how it looks like in gltf after export in aframe

[image]

I have tried so many combinations of export settings and played around with lighting within a-frame but unable to get the model in aframe to look like the one in Blender.

I will be grateful if someone could please help.

Comment: What version of A-Frame are you using? In the latest (`0.8.2`) try adding `renderer="gammaOutput: true"` to your scene entity.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thank you. It did improve the scene but the texture is still not as good as I see on Blender.

Comment: Could you clarify "as good"? Appearance in a realtime engine may not be as good as an offline render... Are the remaining issues lighting, or does color still appear wrong?

Comment: You are right, the difference in quality is only due to the offline v/s the realtime engine view. Thanks Don, as always, for your help

Comment: I don't think the issue is with your export/import - the difference would be in the lighting used. blenders viewport lighting setup can be viewed in [preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/system.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get correct color output, you'll often want to set `gammaOutput` on the renderer:

three.js

```
renderer.gammaOutput = true;
```

A-Frame 0.8.2+

```
<a-scene renderer="gammaOutput: true"> ...
```

Beyond that, color is also a factor of lighting and various differences related to realtime engines vs offline rendering. The [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) is a good place to discuss particular visual effects if you have questions.

Comment: This worked and it seems to be `renderer="colorManagement: true"` now.

Comment: After `gammaOutput` property [was removed in favor of](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/a5ff410c09f7c5a54f0f378681730bd220c8ea41) `outputEncoding` in three.js, `renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.GammaEncoding;` seems to give the correct appearance for the texture in my case (using `THREE.sRGBEncoding` yields the same result visually).